# Convert all text instances to links (unless already enclosed in <a></a>)

Tags: jquery

I want to set something up to find all instances of selected words and convert them to same-page links, with the exception of anything which is already a link or otherwise enclosed in an anchor tag.

So that for example:

```
makelinkfunction("text_string", "link")
```

would convert this:

```
<p>
Here is a text_string to dynamically link.<br/>
This <a href="www.google.com">text_string</a> links elsewhere.
<a name="link">This text_string is within the default link destination.<a/>
</p>
```

into this:

```
<p>
Here is a <a href="#link">text_string</a> to dynamically link.<br/>
This <a href="www.google.com">text_string</a> links elsewhere.
<a name="link">This text_string is within the default link destination.<a/>
</p>
```

The "text_string" instance on the first line is converted to a link, while the other two, being already enclosed in  tags, are left alone.

EDIT:
This is not a duplicate question. I am not just looking for a script to convert all instances of a string into a link. I have found several possible solutions for that (tthe one I've chosen to go with is to use Ben Alman's jQuery replaceText plugin, because it is versatile and easy to use, but I am in no way tied to it.)

I need to be able to add exceptions, as I stated, for instances of text which are already enclosed by  tags.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I convert this hyperlink generator script to this? Not a duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46045469/how-can-i-convert-this-hyperlink-generator-script-to-this-not-a-duplicate)

Answer (score 1):

Create jQuery prototype function;

```
$.fn.makeLink = function(a, b) {

        //Setting function options...
        var options= {

            //Rename function arguments
            insideText: a,
            url: b,

            //Static html
            html: $(this).html(),

            //Already existing anchors
            existsAnchorRGX: new RegExp('<a.*?>.*?' + a + '.*?</a>', 'gi'),
            existsAnchor: [],

            //insadeText RegExp
            insideTextRGX: new RegExp(a, 'gi'),
            insideTextAnchor: '<a href="' + b + '">' + a + '</a>',

            //Temp already anchors
            temp: '<!-- ML:TEMP -->',
            tempRGX: new RegExp('<!-- ML:TEMP -->', 'gi'),

            //Output Html
            outputHtml: $(this).html()

        };

        //loop already anchors and push
        while(alreadyAnchor = options.existsAnchorRGX.exec(options.html))
            options.existsAnchor.push(alreadyAnchor[0]);

        //delete already anchors temporarily
        options.outputHtml = options.outputHtml.replace(options.existsAnchorRGX, options.temp);

        //replace not anchors string
        options.outputHtml = options.outputHtml.replace(options.insideTextRGX, options.insideTextAnchor);

        //replace temp to anchors
        while(options.tempRGX.exec(options.outputHtml)) {
            options.outputHtml = options.outputHtml.replace(options.temp, options.existsAnchor[0]);
            options.existsAnchor.shift();
        }

        //write output html
        $(this).html(options.outputHtml);

        //Reset function options
        option = {};
    };
```

And use;

```
//$('p').makeLink('text_string', 'link');
$('body').makeLink('text_string', 'link');
```

Comment: Hey sorry :)I forgot this. Please append make link function 'option reseter' like; option = {}

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure what you mean or where to put that. You're saying to create a function to reset options to an empty array? Where do I call that from?

Comment: I discovered the problem was using the <p> tags (of which there are multiple instances) as the context for the function calls. If I change it to the body or the enclosing <div> instead, it works as desired! https://jsfiddle.net/Malkalypse/50az8h99/9/

Comment: I'm having an issue with protecting existing links. Right now the link in the anchor has to exactly match the text, where I want to protect ALL existing links. It's causing some strange results: http://versatileartist.com/tmp/cancer_treatments01a.htm ... I know that I need to change the definition for `existsAnchorRGX` to use a wildcard rather than the `a` variable, but I'm afraid I don't know enough about regular expressions to know how to change it. (Look at the wikipedia links for albumin, etc. to see what I'm talking about)

Comment: Okay, I figured out that "find any anchor" is as simple as changing the definition to `existsAnchorRGX: new RegExp('<a.*?>.*', 'gi')` ... however, this does cause considerable slowdown, especially if the function needs to be run for dozens of different definitions. Is there a way to make it look for anchors which contain the specified text value as PART of the anchor? I.e. like `^.*mytext.*$` but for anchors?