# javascript regexp: find anchors containing string inside tag OR inside tag

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following which checks for string str inside the text portion of an anchor, i.e. `<a href="#">text containing str</a>`:

```
RegExp('<a.*?>.*?str.*?</a>', 'gi')
```

However, I need it to check inside the tag as well, i.e. for `<a href="link_containing_str">some text</a>` as well.

I tried the following but it does not work:

```
RegExp('<a.*?str.*?</a>', 'gi')
```

What syntax do I need to use for this?

Comment: don't use a regex for that....

Comment: Like @DanielA.White says, regex on HTML is not the best idea.  But anyway, your regex is missing an escape for the `/`, so  `<a.*?str.*?<\/a>`

Comment: If you explain more your goal, we will be able to offer you alternative solution. Regex is not the best way to do it. Take a look at https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_node_attributes4 
If you know that you always look at the href attribute, you can use the attribute itself (element.href). Then you can also look at the innerHtml part or text part. A lot of way to do it.

Comment: My situation and the solution which was previously provided (which solves for string in text, but not in anchor tag) can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46061840/convert-all-text-instances-to-links-unless-already-enclosed-in-a-a/

Comment: The `<a.*?str.*?<\/a>` suggestion is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using Regex, just check for the existence of the string in the `innerHTML` or `href` properties on the object:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('a').forEach(x => {
  console.log(x.innerHTML.includes('str') || x.href.indexOf('str') != -1);
})
```

```html
<a href="#">text containing str</a>
<a href="link_containing_str">some text</a>
<a href="#">text</a>
<a href="link">some text</a>
```

Comment: Unfortunately this does not answer the question I asked and would require making additional changes to my existing code that I do not know how to make, and are outside the scope of the question I asked.